# How to make a product page in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am learning Wordpress currently so far I know how to design the webpage, but what I want to do next is to make a product page without ordering. What I want is the following:

1. List all my products and if one clicks on a product it will show the detail page of that product
2. The products can be added to a list and then there will be a contact form which will take the list and send it to me in a pdf or excel (but at first enough if only names are sent via email) so I can answer it with the asked question.

I sadly could not find any starting point I do not even know if there is such a plugin, if not can I make one myself? I know javascript so I think I could Programm it myself but would prefer if there is some plugin I can use due to time issues.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: The problem with this as far as I understand, this will make an interface like a shop but I do not want this, I want a normal interface where products can be marked and then sent via email

Answer (score 0):

You can also use woocommerce. If you don't want a user to order something with a "Add to cart" button you could hide this button with your code or a pluging for example https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-catalog-mode/